# Android studio cannot download commons-compress-1.12.jar, can i download commons-compress-1.12.jar on browser and paste to location on gradle?

Tags: java, android-studio, gradle

When i open Android Studio, Android Studio will download `commons-compress-1.12.jar` from `https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/apache/commons/commons-compress/1.12/commons-compress-1.12.jar` 
But still show error `read time out`

So i tried to download from browser and paste into location of `gradle` But i don't know where is location. how can i do ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to paste the files .jar that you download into the libs folder. yourproject -> app -> libs. Regards!

Comment: i paste `commons-compress-1.12.jar` file  into `C:\Users\myusername\AndroidStudioProjects\SMSAPI\app\libs` but when open android studio it's still load file from `https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/apache/commons/commons-compress/1.12/commons-compress-1.12.jar` and then still `read time out`

Comment: it always takes time to load new .jar files. if it takes a long time you can go to build -> clean project/ rebuild project.

Comment: Maybe it's a network problem. you can see the connection status or go to Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build tools -> Gradle -> Offline work